# how to create a connection pool/only once for a third party Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, connection-pooling

I'm using JAVA/Spring MVC and I need to make a Connection Pool for a Third Party Application integration in my application becouse when i try to connect it multiple time my application and server System utilize 100% RAM.

here i have to problem, when users start to hit a specific method (`callGenerationService()`) multiple time, my Heap memory(RAM space) increases and becomes 100% and application going to slow becouse of it connect third party application multiple times ? here i need to create a `connection` only once and get it multiple times. where my connection like,

```
public class ClickToCallServiceImpl implements ClickToCallServiceInterface {
Client client = null;
@Override
public ClickToCall callGenerationService(ClickToCall clickToCall) {
     client = new Client();
     client.connect("127.0.0.1", 8021 , "password", 10); //Every time Connection Connect.
     client.setEventSubscriptions("plain", "all");
     // client.sendSyncApiCommand("",""); //here i run command on every hit like.
    client.sendSyncApiCommand(clickToCall.command1, clickToCall.command2);
    client.close();
}
}
```

> and here 'ClickToCall' is a @Component Bean/POJO Class with variables setters and getters.

Is there, how to we create a `connection (either pool or only once connect)` for above connection where i connect only once and hit `clickToCall.Command1 and clickToCall.Command2` multiple times and utilize less RAM? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Client is it any library class or your own?

Comment: This is a library Class belongs to Freeswitch ESL Technology

Comment: is it  org.freeswitch.esl.client.inbound.Client ?

Comment: yes it is org.freeswitch.esl.client-0.9.2.jar

Comment: You may use [commons pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) in order to create your own pool  [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html) you can find some samples. In any case are you sure you close and release resources after you sent command?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata , Can you create a dummy example here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that I'm not an expert of freeswitch esl so you must check the code properly. Anyway this is what I would do.

First I create a *Factory for Client*

```
public class FreeSwitchEslClientFactory extends BasePooledObjectFactory<Client> {

    @Override
    public Client create() throws Exception {
        //Create and connect: NOTE I'M NOT AN EXPERT OF ESL FREESWITCH SO YOU MUST CHECK IT PROPERLY
        Client client = new Client();
        client.connect("127.0.0.1", 8021 , "password", 10);
        client.setEventSubscriptions("plain", "all");
        return client;
    }

    @Override
    public PooledObject<Client> wrap(Client obj) {

        return new DefaultPooledObject<Client>(obj);
    }
}
```

Then I create a shareable `GenericObjectPool`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"it.olgna.spring.pool"})
public class CommonPoolConfig {

    @Bean("clientPool")
    public GenericObjectPool<Client> clientPool(){
        GenericObjectPool<Client> result = new GenericObjectPool<Client>(new FreeSwitchEslClientFactory());
        //Pool config e.g. max pool dimension
        result.setMaxTotal(20);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Finally I use the created pool in order to get the Client obj:

```
@Component
public class FreeSwitchEslCommandSender {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("clientPool")
    private GenericObjectPool<Client> pool;

    public void sendCommand(String command, String param) throws Exception{
        Client client = null;
        try {
            client = pool.borrowObject();
            client.sendSyncApiCommand(command, param);
        } finally {
            if( client != null ) {
                client.close();
            }
            pool.returnObject(client);
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test (also because I can't) it but it should work. In any case I pray you to properly check the configuration. I don't know if it's OK to always create a Client object and connect or if it's better to connect when you want to send command

I hope it can be useful

**EDIT INFORMATION**

Sorry I made an error early. You must return the client to the pool
I updated my FreeSwitchEslCommandSender class

Angelo

Comment: Hello, @AngeloImmediata Thanks to share this pool concept it working fine for me and also clear the my concept about pool. Thank you so much..

Comment: can you explain here please  `pool.returnObject(client);` ? Thanks.

Comment: Basically it returns the client instance to the pool so that this instance is available for other calls. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#returnObject-T-